# How to manually set interval between n_retrys in autosys job

Tags: intervals, autosys

I need an autosys job to execute every 15 minutes in the interval 12:00 - 14:00. However, i need it to not re-run once it goes to SUCCESS.

I had initially used start_mins and run_window to set up this behavior but using this i can't stop the job from re-running once it goes to success. Also, if i set up n_retrys with start_times, the job gets re-run immediately after failure.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

NOTE: this is for R5 Autosys

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to get your process to spit out some sort of succes file and check for that file exists when the process starts up.

Thats how we did this at the last place I worked at and it was quite simple to implement